# Inner product doubt

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have a doubt about a problem involving inner product spaces. The exercise is:

Given the subspace generated by the vectors $ (1,1,1) $ and $ (1,-1,0) $, find the orthogonal subspace and give a basis.

Now, what I understood of this problem is that I have to find the orthogonal complement. But they don´t give me any inner product to work with. Does the orthogonal complement vary with the product? Which one should I use?

I haven´t seen much of inner product, just the basic, but I should be able to solve this. Thank you! If you do not understand something, please ask me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The orthogonal component depends on the inner product. However, typically the inner product that is chosen (assuming you are dealing with a vector space over real numbers) is the following one:
$$\langle(x_1,x_2,x_3), (y_1,y_2,y_3) \rangle = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3$$

Comment: Thanks! That's all i needed to know. So, if they don't clarify which inner product they are using, I just go with the typical one?

Comment: @LunaSage Yes ${}{}$

Comment: @LunaSage "The typical one" being called the *Euclidean* scalar (or inner) product, in case you need to search for it on the internet or in the literature.